# Change text of button on ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been struggling with changing text of the button that triggered my ajax request to show data has been sent to the server successfully.

## Markup

Using laravel, I have this form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'panel/update/user', 'style' => 'display:inline', 'id' => 'ajax')) }}

    {{ Form::hidden('action', 'confirm') }}
    {{ Form::hidden('user', $confirmed->username) }}

      <button class="btn-xs btn-default pull-right btn" style="padding: 1px 5px;" type="submit" data-after="User Confirmed">Confirm User</button>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

and for javascript:

```
$('form#ajax').on('submit', function(){
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){

            $('#console p').text(response); // This is logging the response from the server in a little console I built.



            /*
            | If data-after is set, then set the value to the button that triggered this 
            */


            if(this.attr('data-after').length) {

                console.log(this);

            }



        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

any form with the id of `#ajax` will be submitted with ajax. I am now trying to implement a way to specify some data attributes to show text to the current button that triggered the submit to show the form was submitted. So `data-after="Submitted"` will change the text from `Confirm` => `Submitted` on success. I want this per form, not to change all.

## Problem

This is ***not*** my only form on the page. The purpose is to fetch unconfirmed users from a database, then confirm them by clicking the button sending data to the server via ajax. After the data is sent, I want to change the text in the button to the text specified in `data-after`. I have multiple forms with ***multiple*** data-after's so I don't want to change all buttons. This is where I'm getting stuck. I want to show that the form was submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could target the button at the beginning of the submit event, and then reference it inside the `success` method.

Abbreviated example:

```
$('form#ajax').on('submit', function() {
        var $button = $(this).find('button');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                // button manipulation here
                $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Submitted');
            }
        });

});
```